# New to SQL - Trying to add a foreign key to my table but getting error (key column ' ' does not exist)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to SQL and I am trying to create a recipe database. Currently I have 2 tables set up that I am trying to join with a foreign key but I keep getting an error when trying to add the key.

**First table:**

```
CREATE TABLE recipe(
recipeID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
recipeName VARCHAR(255),
created TIMESTAMP,
updated TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (recipeID)
);
```

**Second table:**

```
CREATE TABLE instructions (
instructionsID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
specification LONGTEXT,
listOrder INT,
PRIMARY KEY (instructionsID),
FOREIGN KEY (recipeID) REFERENCES recipe(recipeID)
);
```

**Error:**
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'recipeID' doesn't exist in table

**recipe Table info:**

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| recipeID | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| recipeName | varchar(255) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| created | timestamp | NO |  | current_timestamp() | on update current_timestamp() |
| updated | timestamp | NO |  | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |  |

**instructions Table info:**

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| instructionsID | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| specification | longtext | YES |  | NULL |  |
| listOrder | int(11) | YES |  | NULL |  |

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOREIGN KEY (recipeID) REFERENCES recipe(recipeID)
```

Here you are referencing recipeID from recipe to recipeID in instructions table. You don't have a recipeID in instructions table.I think you need to create recipeID column first and then reference it with recipeID in recipe table

```
 CREATE TABLE instructions (
    instructionsID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    specification LONGTEXT,
    listOrder INT,
    recipeID INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (instructionsID),
    FOREIGN KEY (recipeID) REFERENCES recipe(recipeID)
    );
```

THis will work i guess.

Comment: Almost. The column `recipeID` in the `instructions` table must be the same structure as the reference table. Hence, it should be `recipeID INT UNSIGNED`. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=970e22e7b9c8386a4480e1d260acc610)

Comment: AHH..thank you...corrected it...

Comment: Ah! So simple! Thank you very much, I understand now.